# Requirements for mysql database in node.js server

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've installed node.js on my pc and created a server. Now, I'm trying use mysql module but it never connects with the database. I think I did not installed enough requirements for it.
I just installed the mysql module with the command:

```
npm install mysql
```

Please tell me what should I install now? Do I need mysql cluster installed? Or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

### To install the MySQL node.js driver:

If you run just `npm install mysql`, you need to be in the same directory that your run your server. I would advise to do it as in one of the following examples:

#### For global installation:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

#### For local installation:

1- Add it to your `package.json` in the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mysql": "~2.3.2",
     ...
```

2- run `npm install`

---

Note that for connections to happen you will also need to be running the mysql server (which is node independent)

### To install MySQL server:

There are a bunch of tutorials out there that explain this, and it is a bit dependent on operative system. Just go to google and search for `how to install mysql server [Ubuntu|MacOSX|Windows]`. But in a sentence: you have to go to http://www.mysql.com/downloads/ and install it.

Comment: Thanks fmsf, for your answer But how can I create mysql server?